# Does a gyroscope get impacted by gravity?

Tags: kalman-filters, motion-estimation

When processing IMU data, does the gyroscope get impacted by gravity? Linear accelerometers need to have gravity compensation but nothing is said of IMU.

Answer (score 1):

Not by gravity, but remember you're standing on a giant ball spinning in space...

Comment: That's true, but is it significant enough to require compensation or does other noise drown it out?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the gyro.

In practical terms, yes, gyroscopes can be sensitive to acceleration.  I used to use gyros in my work that came with a sensitivity to acceleration in their spec sheet.

I don't recall seeing a specification for this in the silicon MEMS gyros like you find in cell phones.  This probably means that they are crappy enough in other areas that any sensitivity to acceleration is drowned out, or that the manufacturer doesn't care.

So -- study your data sheet.  If you're pushing the gyro to the edges of its capability, study the data sheet *hard*, and verify your physical assembly (because assembly mechanical and electrical details can impact your gyro performance).

And, as a parting shot: if you have a *really really good* gyro, then you'll have to worry about relativistic effects.  Other than frame dragging, and possibly time dilation changing the gain as you move up and down in Earth's curved space-time I don't know what these *are* -- but they're there.  If you're working with a gyro like that, though, you'll know by the billion-dollar budget of the project you're working on, and the fact that over half of your co-workers have PhDs.